# why isn't fscanf() working?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int test, l , b, sqr, area, sqra, num;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &test);
    while(test--) {
        fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &l, &b);    //input:
        area = l * b;                      //2
        sqr = sqrt(area);                  //2 2
        sqra = sqr * sqr;                  //7 9
        while(sqr) {
            if(!(area % sqra)) {
                num = area / sqra;
                --sqr;
                break;
            }
        } 
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my code does not works when test >= 2. I think the problem is with fscanf. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: Where and how do you declare `num`? Also, if the square root of `area` is less than one, then the result will be truncated to zero in `sqr` (meaning the loop will not run and `num` will most likely contain a random value).

Comment: To help you find the problem, I suggest you run your program in a debugger, line by line, while checking the results of all calculations.

Comment: You should provide some example input.

Comment: can you explain why fscanf is not working?

Comment: Since you don't test the return value from `fscanf()`, you have no clue about whether `fscanf()` is working or not.  You **must** pay attention to the return value from the `scanf()` family of functions (indeed, most input functions).  `if (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &test) != 1) ... process error...` and `if (fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &l, &b) != 2) ... process error...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it has to do anything with scanf, for example: if l=2 and b=3 then area=6, sqrt(area) is int so it's being rounded to 2, then sqra=4, area%sqra is then 6%4=2, so it never goes into the condition in the loop which creates an infinite loop.

Same goes to the 2nd input in your example : 7*9=63 => sqr=7 => sqra = 49 => area%sqra=14. Again, infinite loop.

Comment: i have --sqr in loop. in the end i will get sqr = 1, therefore 6%1 = 0

Comment: Not in the code you posted. in your code the `--sqr` happens only if the condition evaluate to true and with l=7,b=9 that doesn't happen

Answer (score 1):

You should really use scanf, not fscanf for this, and, also, where did you declare num at? I'm surprised it compiles at all. Also, the case where you have area is not divisible by sqra will have an infinite loop. (such as a rectangle with sides 3 and 7)

Comment: num is declared (it's the last variable)

Answer (score 1):

[after declaring num]
Your fscanf works fine:

```
    fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &l, &b);
    printf("inp: %d %d\n",l,b);
```

Try printing the user input. it works. Your code logic is wrong so that only you are not getting expected result.